# Is there any way to simplify this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure that never finishes executing. Although the table is indexed, it fails even for 80,000 records. I tried with an Adam Machanic script and found the below statements never terminate. I know the problem is somewhere after the where clause.

P.S. Parameter sniffing is not the case.

```
insert into ProcessedFile_396 (Name,Phone,Title,Address,company,domain,SIC,NAICS,Industry,Email,UploadedB2bFiled_id) select  
  b.Name,
  b.Phone,
  b.Title, 
  case when isnull(b.Street,'') <> '' then isnull(b.Street,'') +',' else '' end  +
   case when isnull(b.city,'') <> '' then isnull(b.city,'') + ',' else '' end +
   case when isnull(b.state,'') <> '' then isnull(b.state,'') + ',' else '' end +
   case when isnull(b.zip,'') <> '' then isnull(b.zip,'') + '.' else '' end as Address,
  (select top 1 Company from CompanyWebsite where domain = b.domain) as Company,
  b.domain,
  b.SIC,
  b.NAICS,
  b.Industry,
  b.Email,
  B2bFiled_id 
from 
  UploadedFile_396 a, B2bDB b 
where 
  ((a.CompanyDomain = b.domain and ISNULL(a.CompanyDomain,'') <> '')) 
  and 
  ((a.Name = b.Name or a.FirstName = b.FirstName or a.LastName = b.LastName or a.MiddleName = b.MiddleName) 
   and 
   (ISNULL(a.Name,'') <> '' or ISNULL(a.FirstName,'') <> '' or ISNULL(a.LastName,'') <> '' or ISNULL(a.MiddleName,'') <> '' )) 
 group by 
   B2bFiled_id,b.Name,b.Phone,b.Title,b.Street,b.City,b.State,b.Zip,b.domain,b.domain,b.SIC,b.NAICS,b.Industry,b.Email
```

Comment: Almost certainly. What on earth are you trying to do?

Comment: Name join is probably producing zillions of records. Empty middle name has lots of matches, single character middle name also, and the same is valid for FirstName and LastName in perhaps lesser extent.

Comment: @podiluska comparing 4 set of fields.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović thanks, any easier way around?

Comment: You need to explain what you want to do. There should be clean join between `a` and `b`. What if user uploaded many files? You will still have duplicates.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović, user uploads a file with certain fields like domain/company name,and the application appends other fields like email,phone,address,SIC etc. here B2bdb is the mother table and the uploadedfile_369 is the uploaded file.The suffix changes with each file upload so their is no issue when user uploads one or more files.Duplicates,i can remove with a single line code at the end.The important is,the SP must finish execution!! THANKS

Comment: Then you need to add UserID field to both tables. You **must** have a way of uniquely identifying your users. If it is not possible, try removing name comparation based on name components. Leave `a.Name = b.Name` only.

Comment: start with getting rid of the implicit joins, they are a SQL antipattern.

Comment: @HLGEM how it is possible?please help

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two things.  First, SQL Server could be doing a sub-optimal optimization of the query.  However, it is not that complicated, so that may not be the reason.

A more likely cause is the join on the domains.  My guess is that you have a domain with thousands or tens of thousands of examples.  In the join, this produces millions (or billions) of candidate rows, which would explain the poor performance.  Blank is an obvious candidate for this, but you eliminate blanks.

Doing "or"s in joins can be problematic.  Try running the query with matches just on one of the fields (say Name) to see whether that returns in a finite amount of time.  If so, one solution would be to break the query into four, and union them together.